# Single RegEx expressiong to decode CSV with embedded dobule quotes and Commas

Tags: c#, .net, regex, excel, csv

I have lots of CSV data that I am trying to decode using regex.  I am actually tried to build on an existing code base that other people/projects hit and dont want to risk breaking their data flows by refactoring the class too much.  So, I was wondering if it is possible to decode this text with a single regex (which is how the class works currently):

```
f1,f2,f3,f4,f5,f6,f7
,"clean text","with,embedded,commas.","with""embedded""double""quotes",,"6.1",
```

First row is the header.  If I save this as xxx.csv and open in Excel, it properly decompiles it to read (note the space between the fields are the cell breaks):

```
f1  f2  f3  f4  f5  f6  f7
clean text  with,embedded,commas.   with"embedded"double"quotes     6.1
```

But when I try this in .net, I get stuck on the regex.  I have this:

```
string regExp = "(((?<x>(?=[,\\r\\n]+))|\"(?<x>([^\"]|\"\")+)\"|(?<x>[^,\\r\\n]+)),?)";
```

You can see it in action here:

http://ideone.com/hRq8xe

Which results in this:

```
<start>

clean text
with,embedded,commas.
with""embedded""double""quotes

6.1
<end>
```

This is very close but it does not replace the escaped double-double quotes with a single-double quote like Excel does.  I could not come up with a regex that worked better.  Can it be done?

Comment: you are taking the hardest possible route to accomplish your goal

Comment: use a [csv parser](http://www.filehelpers.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can somehow manage to match your string using **regular-expression-conditionals** with the following constructors:

- **if-then sentence**`(?(?=regex)then|else)`
- **multiple if-then sentences**`(?(?=condition)(then1|then2|then3)|(else1|else2|else3))`

I came up with the following pattern in order to match the body of your text: `([^\,]+(?(?=[^\,])([^\"]+")|([^\,]+,)))`, however, you will need to put an extra effort in order to create a completly matching expression for your text or end up using a file parser. If so, You can take a look at [FileHelpers](http://filehelpers.sourceforge.net/), a pretty neat library for parsing text files.

Sources:

- [Regular Expression Conditionals](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)
- [Alternation Constructs in Regular Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36xybswe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for effort Eder.  I was not able to get the expression to do it so I ended up going a different route by refactoring in a way that would not change the default behavior.